# iptables bad argument '80'

Tags: iptables, kali-linux

I am running KALI-linux, and i am trying to execute this command:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp –destination-port 80 -j REDIRECT –to-ports 10000
```

i get this as response:
"Bad argument `80'"

Is there something i'm missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you only have one dash for the long flags. `-destination-port` should be `--destination-port`, `-to-ports` should be `--to-ports`. You could also use `--dport` instead of `--destination-port`.

Answer (score -1):

Write --dport instead of --destination-port and instead of -to-port write --to-port .Then it should work.

root@kali# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 1000